# How can I get the sum (average) value of three lists in C#?

Tags: c#, image, list, average

I have three lists which each list represents only 0s and 1s which related to the pixel values of three images.
My question is how can I get the sum (average) of those three lists and represent it in a new list?
here is example of my image1:

```
List<int> image1 = new List<int>();
        int blackColor = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < bmp1.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp1.Height; y++)
            {
                Color color = bmp1.GetPixel(x, y);

                if (color.ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb())
                {
                    image1.Add(0);
                    blackColor++;                        
                }
                else
                {
                    image1.Add(1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are going to want to take a look at SelectMany

Comment: could you please give me some resources or examples?

Comment: Grant Winney;No, basically what i need to do is to get the average value of all the zero elements (element number zero of the list) and put it in the new list and therefore for all the elements of all three lists.

Comment: SelectMany flattens lists into a single list. From there you would just call Average (linq) on them. Here is a post on SelectMany: http://www.dotnetperls.com/selectmany

Comment: (Tangentially related: You might find using GetPixel() in a loop to be too slow for large images. If so, look into using [Bitmap.LockBits()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Answer (score 10):

Let me makes sure I understand the problem. You have three lists of the same length:

```
list A:  1, 2, 4, 3
list B:  3, 2, 4, 1
List C:  2, 7, 1, 8
```

and you wish to get a third list that is the average of each:

```
List D:  2, 4, 3, 4
```

Yes?

This is a job for zip join.

```
var sumOfFirstTwo = list1.Zip(list2, (x, y)=>x + y);
```

`sumOfFirstTwo` is now the sequence that is the sum of the first two lists.

```
var sumOfAllThree = sumOfFirstTwo.Zip(list3, (x, y)=>x + y);
```

`sumOfAllThree` is now the sequence that is the sum of all three lists.

```
var average = sumOfAllThree.Select(x=>x/3).ToList();
```

Make sense?

Comment: Eric Lippert; your understanding of the problem is correct, however as i understood zip only can take up to two inputs. but if i have more than 5 lists what can i do? is that method efficient you think?!

Comment: @user3379918: You said you had three lists; if the question you intended to ask was "I have an arbitrary number of lists, how do I zip them together", that's a completely different question so **ask a new question**.  As for whether any operation is "efficient": efficiency is defined as value produced divided by resources consumed. Since I do not know what you value or what resources you want to conserve, I and everyone else in the world who is not you cannot answer that question.

Comment: Make it a recursive function if you don't know the number of lists.

Comment: @Brandon: That sounds like an arbitrarily deep recursion; what if there are ten thousand lists? We don't want to recurse ten thousand times.

Comment: could you please give me an example what you mean exactly?

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, you're right.. The number of lists can get messy. OP: Your question has been answered quite well with the above answer. I won't define for you what recursion is etc... (I think you have some research to do) as there's more than enough resources and examples on the internet to answer that question. The above answer is exactly what you asked.

Comment: @EricLippert: What is ZIP JOIN ?

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: Zip join takes two sequences, usually of equal length, and joins the first items of both, then the second, then the third... like the two halves of a zipper joining together.

Answer (score 1):

This works for an arbitrary number of lists

```
var firstList = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 1 };
var secondList = new[] { 2, 3, 1, 1 };
var thirdList = new[] { 3, 1, 2, 2 };
var lists = new[] { firstList, secondList, thirdList };

var listLengths = lists.Select(x => x.Count());
if (listLengths.Distinct().Count() != 1)
    throw new Exception("Line lengths must be the same");
var lengthOfEachList = listLengths.First();
var averages = new List<double>();
for (var i = 0; i != lengthOfEachList; ++i) {
    averages.Add(lists.Average(x => x[i]));
}
```

The LINQ way would be

```
var averages = Enumerable.Range(0, lengthOfEachList).Select(x => lists.Average(y => y[x]));
```